# Rails 404 not found for existing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, reactjs, controller

I have a rails application in which I'm trying to add a future to ban existing users. My react request is as follows:

```
handleUserBan(evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();
 let user_id = evt.target.dataset.userId;
 API.put('admin/users/'+user_id, {user: {banned: true}}, function(res) {
   this.loadUsers();
 }.bind(this))
}
```

And my 'UsersController' inside `admin namespace` is:

```
before_action :enforce_admin!

def show
    @user = User.find(ban_params[:id])
end


def update
    @user = User.find(ban_params[:id])
    prms = ban_params

    if prms.include?(:banned)
        @user.update_attributes!(prms)
        @user.save!
        return render :status=>200, :json => {success: true}
    end

end

private

def ban_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:banned)
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

`ActiveRecord: Record not found`
`Couldn't find User with 'id'=`

Even though a user exists with the selected id in my database. My request is structured as follows:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"user"=>{"banned"=>"true"},
"id"=>"7",
"format"=>"json"}
```

And here are my routes for admin namespace:

```
namespace :admin do
    put 'ban_user', :to => 'users#ban_user'
      resources :charges
      resources :coaches
      resources :events
      resources :invoices
      resources :reviews
      resources :users
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just `params[:id]` instead of `ban_params[:id]`

method `ban_params` will return only value of `banned` from `params`. In this case `params` contains { id: 'user_id', action: "your action", controller: 'controller', ..., user: { banned: true } }

```
def ban_params
 params.require(:user).permit(:banned)
end
```

Comment: This worked, just a quick follow-up question; why did `params` work even though I didn't define a method like that in my controller? Does this mean that all the params which I send to my controller are accessible through `params` even with filters?

Comment: Yes, you always have access to the raw `params` hash.

Comment: @anonn023432, as I know, yes. `params` method contains all request parameters. 
`def params
     @_params ||= Parameters.new(request.parameters)
  end`

Answer (score 1):

This code is filtering out the `id` parameter, since it's only permitting the `banned` parameter:

```
def ban_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:banned)
end
```

Something like this might work, although it loses the `permit` constraint:

```
params.permit(:id, :user => [:banned])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Even this method works but I used the other solution in this situation because I wanted to keep my `permit` constraint